# How to read skipped file again in Apache Camel route?

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

I am using apache camel `file` component to read all files from a directory. Based on the file size (if file size in list is not similar to what I am currently reading), I want to skip the file and pick it up again in next iteration. Is that possible? My code snipped looks like below:

```
from("file://my/directroy/path/?recursive=true&noop=true&idempotent=false")
.aggregate(constant(true), new AggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(100).completionTimeout(100)
.split(body()).process(new Processor() {
  public void process(Exchange exchange){
     //Move this file only if the size is == new File("thisPath").length();
    // othersize skip this for now and pick it up in next iteration
  }
});
```

Comment: I was facing this issue from AggragationStrategy. It was getting added in the list twice hence the file was loaded twice. Solved this issue by removing AggregationStrategy.

Answer (score 1):

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html

According to documentation, you can use :

```
filterFile (filter)
    

Filters the file based on Simple language. For example to filter on file size, you can use \${file:size} 5000
```

It would look something like:

```
    from(file:{{replayDir}}/?filterFile=${file:size} 5000
```

For Simple language support, please see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Simple

[image]